# Retrieve the PK using @@identity

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity

I'm building a website using ASP.NET and SQL Server, and I use

```
SELECT PK FROM Table WHERE PK = @@identity
```

My question is which is better and more reliable to retrieve the last inserted PK for multiuser website, using `@@identity` or using this:

```
SELECT MAX(PK) FROM Table WHERE PK = Session ("UserID")
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but the recommended way to retrieve the primary key value of the last statement on a connection is to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

@@Identity is particularly risky where you are using triggers, since it returns the last generated identity value, including those generated by triggers flowing on from a statement.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) has the following to say:

> SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY return
>   the last identity values that are
>   generated in any table in the current
>   session. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY
>   returns values inserted only within
>   the current scope; @@IDENTITY is not
>   limited to a specific scope.

You should certainly use SCOPE_IDENTITY() in favour of the MAX(PK) approach - any number of possible future changes could invalidate this method.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2005 and above...

You can do the INSERT and SELECT in one call using the [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564(SQL.90).aspx) clause...

```
INSERT MyTable (col1, col2, ..., coln)
OUTPUT INSERTED.keycol, INSERTED.col1, INSERTED.col2, ..., INSERTED.coln
VALUES (val1, val2, ..., valn)
```

Otherwise, you only use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @David Hall the `@@IDENTITY` keyword returns the most recently created identity for your current connection, not always the identity for the recently added record in your query and may return an incorrect value. Using `MAX(PK)` there is a higher chance for an incorrect value and I'd strongly recommend against using it. To avoid the any race conditions I'd suggest that you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to return the identity of the recently added record in your INSERT SQL Statement or Stored Procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you want to return the just-generated ID to the ASP.NET code (a typical scenario), then @@identity is your friend. In a high-concurrency situation, mak(PK) is not even guaranteed to be the PK you're after.

Comment: You should only use SCOPE_IDENTITY()